# Messing up the dynamic dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to add dropdown list dynamically to a WebApp using `google appscript`. I wrote a few lines of `javascript` code in the client side to communicate the server side to fetch the data from `google-sheets`. After a lot of trying, I'm somewhat successful. However, it looks like, whenever I click on the "Add Product" button, for first 1-2 times the array from which the dropdown is generated is empty. As a result the dropdown remains blank. However after 1 or 2 blank dropdowns the it starts working as it's suppose to.

What am I doing wrong ?

I have 3 files-

1. `form.html`
2. `code.gs`
3. `js_script.html`
4. [Link to the google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YKZYgKctsXU3DKTidVVPUhmPXUkzjjocaiMz1S76JAE/edit#gid=1005138031)

Content of `form.html`-

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <div class = "row">
       <h1>Order Form</h2>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->
      
     <div class = "row">
       <input id="orderno" type="text" class="validate">
       <label for="orderno">Order Number</label>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->

     <div class = "row">
       <input id="clientname" type="text" class="validate">
       <label for="clientname">Client Name</label>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->

     <div class = "row">
       <input id="clientaddr" type="text" class="validate">
       <label for="clientaddr">Client Address</label>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->

     <div class = "row">
       <input id="clientphone" type="text" class="validate">
       <label for="clientphone">Client Phone Number</label>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->
      
     <div class = "row">
       <input id="ordertype" type="text" class="validate">
       <label for="ordertype">Order Type</label>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->

     <div id="productsection"></div>
     <div class = "row">   
       <button id="addproduct">Add Product</button>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->
      
     <div class = "row">
       <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
     </div>                                    <!-- end of row -->                    
   </div>                                      <!-- End of "container" class -->         
   <?!= include("js_script"); ?>
</body>
```

Content of `code.gs`

```
const ssID = "1YKZYgKctsXU3DKTidVVPUhmPXUkzjjocaiMz1S76JAE";
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);

function doGet(e){
  Logger.log(e);
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form").evaluate();
}

function include(fileName){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(fileName).getContent();
}

function appendDataToSheet(userData){
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("orders");

  ws.appendRow([new Date(), userData.orderNumber, userData.clientName, userData.clientAddress, userData.clientPhone, userData.orderType, userData.products].flat());
}

function getOptionArray(){
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("product_list");

  const optionList = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow() - 1).getValues()
              .map(item => item[0]);

  return optionList;
}

function logVal(data){
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

Content of `js_script.html`

```html
<script>
  let counter = 0;
  let optionList = [];
  
  document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", writeDataToSheet);
  document.getElementById("addproduct").addEventListener("click", addInputField);

  function addInputField(){
    counter++;
    
    // The idea is, everytime when "add product" button is clicked, the following element must be added to the "<div id="productoption></div>" tag.

    // <div class="row">
    //   <select id="productX">
    //     <option>option-X</option>
    //   </select>
    // </div>
    
    const newDivTag = document.createElement('div');
    const newSelectTag = document.createElement('select');

    newDivTag.class = "row";
    newSelectTag.id = "product" + counter.toString();

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOptionList).getOptionArray();

    google.script.run.logVal(optionList);                //  This is just to test the optionList array if it's updated or not

    for(let i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++){
      const newOptionTag = document.createElement('option');
      newOptionTag.textContent = optionList[i];
      newOptionTag.value = optionList[i];
      newSelectTag.appendChild(newOptionTag);
    }

    newDivTag.appendChild(newSelectTag);
    document.getElementById('productsection').appendChild(newDivTag);
  }

  function writeDataToSheet(){
    const userData = {};
    userData.orderNumber = document.getElementById("orderno").value;
    userData.clientName = document.getElementById("clientname").value;
    userData.clientAddress = document.getElementById("clientaddr").value;
    userData.clientPhone = document.getElementById("clientphone").value;
    userData.orderType = document.getElementById("ordertype").value;
    userData.products = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      let input_id = "product" + (i+1).toString();
      userData.products.push(document.getElementById(input_id).value);
    }

    google.script.run.appendDataToSheet(userData);
  }

  function updateOptionList(arr){
    optionList = arr.map(el => el);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your current issue of `However, it looks like, whenever I click on the "Add Product" button, for first 1-2 times the array form which the dropdown is generated is empty. As a result the dropdown remains blank. However after 1 or 2 blank dropdowns the it starts working as it's suppose to.`, when I saw your script, I thought that the reason for your issue might be due to that `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

In this case, your `js_script.html` is modified.

#### Modified script:

```html
<script>
let counter = 0;
// let optionList = []; // Removed

document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", writeDataToSheet);
document.getElementById("addproduct").addEventListener("click", addInputField);

// Modified
function addInputField(){
  counter++;
  const newDivTag = document.createElement('div');
  const newSelectTag = document.createElement('select');
  newDivTag.class = "row";
  newSelectTag.id = "product" + counter.toString();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(arr => {
    const optionList = updateOptionList(arr);
    google.script.run.logVal(optionList);
    for(let i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++){
      const newOptionTag = document.createElement('option');
      newOptionTag.textContent = optionList[i];
      newOptionTag.value = optionList[i];
      newSelectTag.appendChild(newOptionTag);
    }
    newDivTag.appendChild(newSelectTag);
    document.getElementById('productsection').appendChild(newDivTag);
  }).getOptionArray();
}

function writeDataToSheet(){
  const userData = {};
  userData.orderNumber = document.getElementById("orderno").value;
  userData.clientName = document.getElementById("clientname").value;
  userData.clientAddress = document.getElementById("clientaddr").value;
  userData.clientPhone = document.getElementById("clientphone").value;
  userData.orderType = document.getElementById("ordertype").value;
  userData.products = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    let input_id = "product" + (i+1).toString();
    userData.products.push(document.getElementById(input_id).value);
  }
  google.script.run.appendDataToSheet(userData);
}

// Modified
function updateOptionList(arr){
  return arr.map(el => el); // I cannot understand this mean.
}
</script>
```

or, in this case, `updateOptionList` might not be required to be used as follows.

```html
<script>
let counter = 0;
// let optionList = []; // Removed

document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", writeDataToSheet);
document.getElementById("addproduct").addEventListener("click", addInputField);

// Modified
function addInputField(){
  counter++;
  const newDivTag = document.createElement('div');
  const newSelectTag = document.createElement('select');
  newDivTag.class = "row";
  newSelectTag.id = "product" + counter.toString();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(optionList => {
    google.script.run.logVal(optionList);
    for(let i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++){
      const newOptionTag = document.createElement('option');
      newOptionTag.textContent = optionList[i];
      newOptionTag.value = optionList[i];
      newSelectTag.appendChild(newOptionTag);
    }
    newDivTag.appendChild(newSelectTag);
    document.getElementById('productsection').appendChild(newDivTag);
  }).getOptionArray();
}

function writeDataToSheet(){
  const userData = {};
  userData.orderNumber = document.getElementById("orderno").value;
  userData.clientName = document.getElementById("clientname").value;
  userData.clientAddress = document.getElementById("clientaddr").value;
  userData.clientPhone = document.getElementById("clientphone").value;
  userData.orderType = document.getElementById("ordertype").value;
  userData.products = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    let input_id = "product" + (i+1).toString();
    userData.products.push(document.getElementById(input_id).value);
  }
  google.script.run.appendDataToSheet(userData);
}
</script>
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you. Can you explain to me to what you are trying to say  about google.script.run being an asynchronous process, as I'm quite new in js.

Comment: @arnieM Thank you for replying. About your reply, in your current script, when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOptionList).getOptionArray();` is run, it is run with the asynchronous process. By this, before `updateOptionList` is finished, the next script is run. By this, the empty dropdown is created by the 1st click. And, at the 2nd click, `optionList` created at the 1st click is used. If you continuously click the button, even when 2nd click, `optionList` might be still empty.

Comment: @arnieM I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So, in this modification, I modified your script for running with the synchronous process. In this modification, when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(,,,).getOptionArray();` is run, first, `getOptionArray()` of Google Apps Script is run, and then, the script in `withSuccessHandler` is run with the asynchronous process. By this, by 1st click, the correct value of `optionList` is used. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Your solution is working for me. It does make sense what you said about `By this, before updateOptionList is finished, the next script is run. By this, the empty dropdown is created by the 1st click. And, at the 2nd click, optionList created at the 1st click is used. If you continuously click the button, even when 2nd click, optionList might be still empty.`. It seems to me I've to study about async processes, for better understanding. Thanks a lot for helping me understand the issue with my code.

Comment: @arnieM Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About my latest reply, I thought that `and then, the script in withSuccessHandler is run with the asynchronous process.` was `and then, the script in withSuccessHandler is run with the synchronous process.`. This is due to my miscopy. I apologize for this.

Comment: Also, I've noticed, now that the dropdown waits for it to fill up with content, it's a bit slower to response when clicked on `add product`. Anyway to make this experience a bit faster?

Comment: @arnieM About `Also, I've noticed, now that the dropdown waits for it to fill up with content, it's a bit slower to response when clicked on add product. Anyway to make this experience a bit faster?`, in this case, when `google.script.run` is used, the process cost is high. I apologize for this. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, if the value of `optionList` is always the same, how about loading it when the HTML is opened? By this, `google.script.run` is not required to be used, and the process cost can be reduced.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would go with your second suggestion I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251167/discussion-between-arniem-and-tanaike).